# XAML trigger setter and property of UIElementCollection type

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styling

My control has property `Buttons` of type `UIElementCollection`. Is it possible to modify such property via triggers (specifically `DataTrigger`)?

I have following code:

```
<Setter Property="Buttons">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Button>A</Button>
        <Button>B</Button>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And I get error "The property value is set more than once". Wrapping the buttons in `UIElementCollection` tag doesn't work (`UIElementCollection` has no default contructor). If I remove the second button, I get exception that the `Buttons` property is not compatible with type `Button`.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to circumvent the issue by modifying (with triggers) individual items of the collection (individual buttons) instead of changing whole collection.

I just hide and show the buttons depending on some conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an attached behavior to modify a collection with a setter.  Here is a working example based on the `Panel.Children` property which is also a `UIElementCollection`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="twoButtons" TargetType="Panel">
            <Setter Property="local:SetCollection.Children">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <x:Array Type="UIElement">
                        <Button Content="Button1"/>
                        <Button Content="Button2"/>
                    </x:Array>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource twoButtons}"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the attached property `SetCollection.Children`:

```
public static class SetCollection
{
    public static ICollection<UIElement> GetChildren(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICollection<UIElement>)obj.GetValue(ChildrenProperty);
    }

    public static void SetChildren(DependencyObject obj, ICollection<UIElement> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Children", typeof(ICollection<UIElement>), typeof(SetCollection), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnChildrenPropertyChanged));

    static void OnChildrenPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = sender as Panel;
        var children = e.NewValue as ICollection<UIElement>;
        panel.Children.Clear();
        foreach (var child in children) panel.Children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** A workaround would be using a converter, define your Buttons in a list in some resources:

```
    <col:ArrayList x:Key="Buttons">
        <Button>A</Button>
        <Button>B</Button>
    </col:ArrayList>
```

Namespace: `xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"`

And use a custom converter in the setter to turn it into a collection:

```
<Setter Property="Buttons" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Buttons}, Converter={StaticResource ListToUIElementCollectionConverter}}"/>
```

**Edit:** Getting this to work properly is not a trivial task since the converter needs to know the parent object for the UIElementCollection-constructor.

Comment: I mentioned that in the original post - that doesn't work, because UIElementCollection has nod default constructor. Maybe it would work if I made a ItemsControl derived container which also implements IList...but that is a little clumsy imo.

Comment: I probably should read questions more closely, well; something that came to my mind was using a converter, added the outline of that to my answer. Not very nice either though.